# Resource Configuration class could not be loaded - Jersey

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, amazon-web-services, jersey

I had developed a server code following the `RESTful` architecture few months back. The server code is hosted on a cloud service and it was working as expected till yesterday. I opened the `Eclipse IDE` to make few changes on the server code (just adding few java classes) and there was an automatic update to my server code on the cloud and the local Tomcat server.

I suddenly find my endpoints not working and I get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource configuration class
 org.abc.def.gh.MyApplication could not be loaded.
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:502)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init(WebComponent.java:324)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



 root cause  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 org.abc.def.gh.MyApplication
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:404)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:394)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init(WebComponent.java:324)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

, where MyApplication is registered the following way in `web.xml`:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.abc.def.gh.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

I have not made any changes both to my `web.xml` and `pom.xml` files. I'm finding it hard to analyse the cause of this sudden issue.

I appreciate your help!
Thanks.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your application. Check you have all the dependencies in the classpath and deployment assembly of your project.

Comment: Thanks. I cleaned the project and the projects it depended on and also fixed few build path issues (incompatible JRE System libraries) and then it works!

Comment: Glad, it worked! Cheers